# If static methods can't be overridden, how its working here (For Java)?

Tags: java, overriding

My understanding was that static variables and static methods are of a class, not of the class objects. So an `Override` of a static method won't work in Java, as for overriding we need an instance of a class to be created. But I was trying something today that contradicted my knowledge of Java.

Please follow this code:

```
class Parent{
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Parent ");
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{    
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Child ");
   }
}

public class StaticPractise{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Parent.doIt();
      Child.doIt();
   }    
}
```

The output of the above implementation is:

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JAVA>java StaticPractise
In static method 'doit' of class Parent
In static method 'doit' of class Child
```

From this output I can understand that though the `Child` class extends the `Parent` class, the `doit` methods are individual to each class as they are `static`. So no overriding of them is allowed.

Now please follow the below code, where `@Override` is added to the child's `doIt` method:

```
class Parent{
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Parent ");
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{    
   @Override // Adding this annotation here
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Child ");
   }
}

public class StaticPractise{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Parent.doIt();
      Child.doIt();
   }    
}
```

The output of the above code gives a compilation error as follows:

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JAVA>javac StaticPractise.java
StaticPractise.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
1 error
```

Here it clearly says that the annotation `Override` can't be applied in `static` methods as they are not getting overridden.

Now please follow the below code, where `Child` has no `doIt` method:

```
class Parent{
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Parent ");
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{ /* no doIt method */ }

public class StaticPractise{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Parent.doIt();
      Child.doIt();
   }    
}
```

The output is:

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JAVA>java StaticPractise
In static method 'doit' of class Parent
In static method 'doit' of class Parent
```

Why does the above code compile and run? I was expecting a compilation error for method `doit` for class Child, and I was expecting "Method not found". I don't understand.

Also please follow the below code. Here, the `doIt` method in `Parent` is now `final`.

```
class Parent{
   public static final void doIt(){ // now final
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Parent ");
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{
   public static void doIt(){
      System.out.println("In static method 'doit' of class Parent ");
   }
}

public class StaticPractise{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Parent.doIt();
      Child.doIt();
   }    
}
```

The output after running the above code is as follows:

```
D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JAVA>javac StaticPractise.java
StaticPractise.java:30: error: doIt() in Child cannot override doIt() in Parent
    public static void doIt(){
                       ^
  overridden method is static,final
 1 error

 D:\Rahul Shivsharan\MyPractise\JAVA>
```

What I was expecting was that the above code should work fine as the `doit` methods are static in each class, so even a `final` keyword should not make any compilation error as the method is `static`.

Please explain to me how method overriding works in static classes in Java.

1. Can static methods be overridden? If yes, then how come annotating `@Override` fails?
2. If static methods can't be overridden, then how come my 3rd code block runs fine?
3. If static methods can't be overridden, then how come the `final` keyword makes a difference?

Comment: Well written question of the day so far :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all there are different mechanisms involved here: [Overriding and Shadowing (also called hiding)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

1)
Static methods cannot be overriden as they are attached to the class they are defined in. However, you can **shadow/hide** a static method as you are doing with your `Parent`/`Child` class. This means, the method gets replaced in the `Child` class but is still available from the `Parent` class.

It gets more obvious that you are **not** overriding when you are calling the static methods from instances of those classes (and not using the `Class.staticMethod()` invocation).

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child1 = new Child();
Parent child2 = new Child();

parent.StaticMethod();
child1.StaticMethod();
child2.StaticMethod();
```

the output is

```
Static method from Parent
Static method from Child
Static method from Parent
```

The answer is the dispatch of the methods. You can grab the [source code here](https://github.com/lschuetze/shadow-static-example)

2)
The dispatch finds the method on the `Parent` class. There is no dynamic dispatch as that the runtime type is used to find the method handle. It uses the compile time type. *Remind*: Calling static methods from instances is considered bad practice since things like above can happen and are easy to be overlooked.

3)
With `final`you declare that the method cannot be overridden neither shadowed/hidden.

Comment: It should further be noted that the compiler is adding to the confusion with its message of `overridden method is static,final`. That should have read shadowed/hidden instead.

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing [overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) with [hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2)

Comment: It creeps me out that "confusing" is also highlighted. :/

Comment: @EralpB, I must agree... by popular demand link to Main secction in JLS that contained in [confusing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) has been erased :D

Answer (score 4):

Although it is discouraged to ask 3 questions in one post, I am still willing to answer them.

1. Static methods cannot be overridden because there is no point of doing that. In your case, If you want to override the static method you can just call the method and add your own implementation after that or you just create another method.
2. So now that you know that static methods cannot be overridden. But you are asking why the third code works? The third code is the code with

   public class Child extends Parent {}

right? Although static methods cannot be overridden, they can be *inherited*. What you are doing is inheriting `Parent` so that is completely fine!

3. Now let me tell you, in your first code sample you are *hiding* the method in the `Parent` class, not overriding. That's why you get the output. A `final` keyword means the method can ***never*** be changed, not even hidden. So that's why.